# Background-image disappear on hover

Tags: hover, background-image

I have a background-image (red plus sign) in an expandable section.

See in this link : http://www.eborrelli.com/clients/RC-site/media/

It disappears on hover, and I don't know how to solve this

My programming skills are very basic.

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you show some code that you use right now?

Comment: In your questions, you should contains the code which potentially doesn't work. Please follow this short tutorial - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not very pretty, but this works.

```
.ult_exp_section {
    background-image: url(http://www.eborrelli.com/clients/RC-site/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/plus-red-30px.png) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: right center !important;
}
```